# How to land to existing page when clicked on refresh and then back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing issue with one of the functionality where in I wrote a code that prevents the user from going to the previous page when clicked on back button. For the same code when I refresh the page and then click on the back button, it lands to the previous page. I do not want this experience and want the user to remain in the same page even though the user refreshes and clicks back button.

The existing code that I have written is below. Can I incorporate something in this or do I need to write a new component?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const popupHandler = () => window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href)

const usePreventBackButton = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
     window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
     window.addEventListener('popstate', popupHandler)
     return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', popupHandler)
   }, [])
}

export default usePreventBackButton
```